# Replacing a string with a given text using Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a file named testfile.It contains some information like

```
methun:x:500:500:comment:/home/methun:bin/bash
salahuddin:x:501:500:comment:/home/methun:bin/bash
```

Now implemented a following shell program:

```
 echo "Enter a Name:"
   read username
   users='cat /mypractice/myfiles/testfile | awk -F ':' '{print $1}''
   for user in $users
    do
      if [ "$user" == "$username" ]; then
        echo "Name found and Enter a new name to change."
        read newUsername
          #need code to change text on my file --->testfile
      fi
    done
```

Now suppose I need to change methun to Moin. Comment to newcomment. I used

```
sed -i 's/"$user"/"$newuser"/g' /mypractice/myfiles/testfile
```

But it not working here. I test with it in my testfile singly it change and replace all.But i need to change only that position i want .

I also tried with usermod but it will not works here..

Can anyone give me the solution or correct my code...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using `g` flag in your `sed` command which means global substitution (will change all occurrences). Also, the variables although quoted are wrapped inside single quotes and hence are not interpolated.

**Try this:**

```
sed -i "s/^$user/$newuser/" /mypractice/myfiles/testfile
```

I have placed a `^` anchor in the substitution part which means only substitute if the word is at the beginning of the line. This protects you from making a change if the name of the user is not at the start but somewhere in the middle.

Comment: But i want to change only the name that match on the if condition.

Comment: @user3464541 Right, just put this `sed` under your `if` condition. So if the condition returns true, you can make the change.

Comment: suppose i have methun, methun1, methun2, methun3. want to replace methun with jon. When i input methun and want to change name with jon then i found the result like jon jon1 jon2 jon3 But my expected result is like jon methun1 methun2 methun3.